# Save Location for Portable Executable

Tags: c++, windows

I want to provide my `portable executable` file as a single `exe` file.

This **exe** file needs some `txt` file to save `logs`. But I do not want user to delete it unintentionally.

Where is the standard way to save such kind of files by executable without requiring `administrative` privileges on `Windows` operating systems?

Portable executable also runs without requiring administrative` privileges.

Also is writing to user system by portable executable recommended? Can anti-virus software complain about that?

Comment: You can only protect your users so much before you become a nanny programmer. I don't see this as a constructive use of time and it's too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: There are files and folders that can not be written. I am asking a suitable and standard folder to write. What is nanny about that?

Comment: The standard location is somewhere in the Users Documents folder. There are windows APIs to get the location. The nanny part is trying to prevent them from accidentally deleting the file.

Comment: SingleExe:check your linker options to use static libraries instead of dynamic libs (DLLs). Where to put the logs? GetTempPath (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364992(v=vs.85).aspx)/GetTempFileName (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364991(v=vs.85).aspx) & please be considerate and not fill the hard drive.  Another option is to use the Windows Event Log (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385780(v=vs.85).aspx) Most users don't even know it exists.  BTW: most apps just put all their files in their own directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The executable should be installed in `"C:\Program Files"` or `"C:\Program Files (x86)"` for 32-bit programs. This installation would require admin access.

Or you can install to `"c:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local"` directory (or any other non-protected directory, such as `"c:\My Programs"`), without admin privileges, but it's unconventional.

Log files and other writable files cannot go to protected ProgramFiles directory. They should be in `"c:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local"`.

User files must be in Documents directory.

Don't forget the program must allow the user to uninstall it. Add uninstall information to to registry key.

```
"c:\\Program Files\\MyCompany\\MyAppName\\app.exe"
"c:\\Users\\UserName\\AppData\\Local\\MyCompany\\MyAppName\\app.exe"

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE //or use HKEY_CURRENT_USER if there is no admin access
    "software\\microsoft\\windows\\currentversion\\uninstall\\My App Name"
        "UninstallString = full-path-uninstall-command"
```

Uninstall string is usually added to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, but if the installer doesn't have admin access it can go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`

To get these folders in Vista or higher, use:

```
std::wstring documents, appData, programFiles;

wchar_t *ptr;
if (S_OK == SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Documents, 0, NULL, &ptr))
{
    documents = ptr;
    CoTaskMemFree(ptr);
}

if (S_OK == SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_LocalAppData, 0, NULL, &ptr))
{
    appData = ptr;
    CoTaskMemFree(ptr);
}

if (S_OK == SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_ProgramFilesX86, 0, NULL, &ptr))
{
    programFiles = ptr;
    CoTaskMemFree(ptr);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Barmak. This is Portable executable. So users downloads it and most generally runs it inside downloads folder. So should I save all extra files inside `c:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local`? Also should executable also copy it itself to AppDataLocal folder?

Comment: Yes, don't forget to make a sub-directory, for example "c:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\MyAppName". Your stand-alone *.exe should be digitally signed, otherwise WindowVista or above will block it. How is this installed? Are you using an installer? over internet?

Comment: No, it is not actually installed. Just runs by double clicking. It is not digitally signed. Windows warns but it can be used if user clicks OK for the warning. Just want to add some additional files in user system so that they do not delete it accidentally.

Comment: You should probably put the package in zip file and allow the user to download and unzip it where they want and just leave it there. The user will download unsigned package only if they trust you, you should respond with the same courtesy. Include readme.txt file to let user know where additional files are being copied.

Comment: OK Thank you. Will add a ReadMe.txt